# Why is a simple webscraping code running slow on pycharm but fast on google colab?

Tags: python, web-scraping

When I run this code on colab it takes ~13 seconds, however in pycharm it takes 1-2 minutes.
Do you guys know why?

```
from google_play_scraper import app
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from google_play_scraper import Sort, reviews_all

us_reviews = reviews_all(
    'com.limeturtle.nexomon',
    sleep_milliseconds=0, # defaults to 0
    lang='en', # defaults to 'en'
    country='us', # defaults to 'us'
    sort=Sort.NEWEST, # defaults to Sort.MOST_RELEVANT
)
```

I'm scraping google appstore review data. I chose a random app.

Comment: do you know what hardware it is running on google colab? That could make a REALLY BIG difference.

Comment: Google has big money for very fast computers, And they use  very fast connection to internet. And this can make so big difference.

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be the time for one request to the Play Store API. For instance:

```
curl -o /dev/null -s -w 'Total: %{time_total}s\n' --location --request POST 'https://play.google.com/_/PlayStoreUi/data/batchexecute?hl=en&gl=us' \                                                                   
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' \
--data-raw 'f.req=%5B%5B%5B%22KT5WVe%22%2C%22%5B1%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C%5B0%5D%5D%22%2Cnull%2C%221%22%5D%5D%5D&'
```

That takes ~1,3s on my local machine and only ~0.06s on Colab. If you then have 50 pages it might sum up.

Comment: Oh thank you! sorry for the delay, I forgot to answer. I guess there is no way around that then